# Deny user to login and alow him after 1 hour

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm trying to block user to login (Because he temporarily banned) and allow him after hour to login again.

Now I've no idea how should I do that, I think that I should use htaccess to deny the user but I dont know how to allow him connect once again.

I'm using xml files as database (I awere security issuses), here is example for my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user>
<name>none</name>
<lastname>none</lastname>
<password>e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e</password>
<birthday>none</birthday>
<country>none</country>
<gender>Male</gender>
<age>1</age>
<email>none</email>
<level>Members</level>
<date>22/06/2013</date>
</user>
```

As you can tell i use md5 for password.

So I want to temporarily ban user for hour then active his account again, how can i do that?

Comment: What prevents you from adding a field into that file which stores until which datetime (timestamp) the user is blocked?

Comment: Add a new filed `banned_date` to the xml database and calculate it.

Comment: @hakre I don't know how to do that..

Comment: @Hast You mean add new child then get the child to my system and calculate it?

Comment: Then you might want to read about that I guess. http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic might be a start for you. Technically you've just posted your requirements, that's discouraged. What we like to get asked about are concrete programming questions that will help all future visitors of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an  tag and save there time of ban. Then in login script add time check and when between current time and ban time there will be less than hour difference show an "you were banned" message.

Comment: But how I can delete the child after 1 hour? Lets assume I get the child, how can i set time to delete him?

Comment: @yotam: You don't need to delete that child. You only need to compare the timestamp with the current timestamp. If it is lower than you allow access.